# The Gatsby Graphql build query can't find my images, but the GraphQL IDE can

Tags: graphql, gatsby

When running either gatsby develop or gatsby build, i sometimes get the error "GraphQL Error Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.".

It seems that the GraphQL query cant find the images somehow. After the build completes (still with the Grapql error), the public/static folder does not contain any images.

To the part that i cant understand:
If i go into the GraphQL IDE at localhost:8000/___graphiql and paste the exact same query as in the JSX file, i get a complete list of the images with all the childImageSharp data and so on

Part of the query:

```
<br>
        image {
          id
          relativePath
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              base64
              tracedSVG
              aspectRatio
              src
              srcSet
              srcWebp
              srcSetWebp
              sizes
              originalImg
              originalName
              presentationWidth
              presentationHeight
            }
          }
        }
```

The result:

```
"image": {
            "id": "beacb126-aec4-596c-b4c0-d5d0d34dd63b",
            "relativePath": "crm-skiss.png",
            "childImageSharp": {
              "fluid": {
...
                "aspectRatio": 2.807017543859649,
                "src": "/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/a3fa0/crm-skiss.png",
                "srcSet":
<br> "/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/e7c66/crm-skiss.png 200w,\n/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/140ea/crm-skiss.png 400w,\n/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/a3fa0/crm-skiss.png 800w,\n/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/4cc84/crm-skiss.png 1200w,\n/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/5faf0/crm-skiss.png 1600w,\n/static/019990c97190e6df658cc49ad26b9634/de95f/crm-skiss.png 1920w",
```

...and so on

As i am querying for these images in the IDE, they are actually created in the /public/static folder in my app.

The weird thing is that the query in the IDE is working, and is able to find the images, while the build query cant.

Comment: video capture of when the files are created in the app https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fmtHd7-D0L68I3KwEaJ57ouEqeijeARj/view

Comment: Do you have different configurations for development and production builds? If so, does the production config point to the same data source?

Comment: Well, i have four different configs, but all that differs between them is the folder path where i add the different /language/ for each country. And i have tried to move all the assets up to the root, but the problem persists.